# How do I make this code only appear for 600px and upwards? (I don't want it appearing on mobile or tablet)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How do I make this code only appear for 600px and upwards? (I don't want it appearing on mobile or tablet).

Here is the code below, sorry if its a mess, I am guessing the fix has something to do with @media line on line 121 ish.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="http://www.cssscript.com/wp-includes/css/sticky.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style>

#allrecords ul {
padding: 0px !important;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
color: #fff;
}

.accordion {
width: 100%;
max-width: 2500px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 690px;
}

.accordion ul {
width: 100%;
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
padding-inline-start: 0px !important;
}

.accordion ul li {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
position: relative;
width: 18%;
height: 750px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
transition: all 500ms ease;

}

.accordion ul li div {
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
}

.accordion ul li div a {
display: block;
display:flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items:center;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
vertical-align: bottom;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.accordion ul li div a * {
opacity: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
position: relative;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
transform: translateX(-20px);
-webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.accordion ul li div a h2 {
font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
text-overflow: clip;
font-size: 24px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.accordion ul li div a p {
top: 25px;
font-size: 13.5px;
}

.accordion ul li:nth-child(1) { background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc? 
export=download&id=1ZBYyMeZ7TEGMj2eeey7M6N3AAZKG5vZs"); }

.accordion ul li:nth-child(2) { background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc? 
export=download&id=1YRADuysiSfjd5jkZnLXSmgMufGQpqnso"); }

.accordion ul li:nth-child(3) { background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc? 
export=download&id=1mMmFbCfhSppCXOtDiF8yTrb-YR_thick"); }

.accordion ul li:nth-child(4) { background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc? 
export=download&id=1HyCs9w20reSLLlNrPPKdKdbSlHHdbZp8"); }

.accordion ul li:nth-child(5) { background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc? 
export=download&id=1yVHKVZbQu67hMlRCzdqL5XPb2nNgwE4-"); }

.accordion ul li:nth-child(6) { background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc? 
export=download&id=194gXHwy49NxS7m40RSUQEUc2Nqkg7V65"); }

.accordion ul li:nth-child(7) { background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc? 
export=download&id=1BIkOC1bzXDGPcqW6QHx5lCojJlD5cEeY"); }

.accordion ul:hover li { width: 8%; }

.accordion ul:hover li:hover { width: 60%; }

.accordion ul:hover li:hover a { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }

.accordion ul:hover li:hover a * {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
transform: translateX(0);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px, max-height: 1200px) {

body { margin: 0; }

.accordion { height: auto; }

.accordion ul li,
.accordion ul li:hover,
.accordion ul:hover li,
.accordion ul:hover li:hover {
position: relative;
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
-webkit-transition: none;
transition: none;
}
}

.about {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;

}

.about a {
color: blue;
text-decoration: none;
}

.about a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
</style>



</head>

<body>

<div class="accordion">
<ul>
<li>
  <div> <a href="#">
    
    </a> </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div> <a href="#">
    
    </a> </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div> <a href="#">
    
    </a> </div>
</li>

<li>
  <div> <a href="#">
    
    </a> </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div> <a href="#">
      
      </a> </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div> <a href="#">
      
      </a> </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div> <a href="#">
    
    </a> </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At a wild guess, given what you already have `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { body { display:none; } }`

Comment: what do you mean by "this code" - all the HTML you posted?

Comment: It's ok now, the solved answer sorted it. Thank you for the help though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a media query and put your css in there:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

}
```

Comment: How would it work for the HTML section at the bottom? as the mobile view is showing bullet points from the HTML li.

Comment: no problem! can you accept my answer please ? Thanks! To remove that bullets you can just use "list-style-type: none;" in your media query for mobile screens.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly I believe you need to change your media query to use

```
min-width: 600px, min-height: 1200px
```

This will then specify your css to only come into play at 600px wide or above and 1200px height or above

This example on w3 schools should provide some more context

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_queries1

Original page for example https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: This doesn't work :(. I have tried all the usual codes from online to do it and doesn't work. I think it is conflicting with a line of code within the CSS but I can't find it.

Comment: It's ok now, the solved answer sorted it. Thank you for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide something on mobile or tablet sizes, you can use this css example:

```
.yourClassName {
  @media (max-width: 700px) {
   display: none;
  }

  @media (max-width: 300px) {
   display: none;
   // something else for smaller sizes
  }
}
```

Comment: You might like to review your css nesting/layout...

Comment: It's ok now, the solved answer sorted it. Thank you for the help though :)

Comment: I am fairly new to new aspects of HTML and CSS, so I am learning aha.

Comment: This answer has `.class` and `@media` around the wrong way - classes go inside `@media` not the other way around.